# C-Style strings versus library string performance

Tags: c++

## Question

Is it true that C-style strings operations, on average, execute 5 times slower than library `string` class operations, as C++ Primer, 4th Edition would have me believe?

### Why ask?

Because when I actually performance test, it turns out that C-style strings are about 50% faster for a particular example (one used in the book).

---

## Setup

I am reading [C++ Primer, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201721481), which (on page 138) lists this code:

```
//  C-style character string implementation
const char *pc = "a very long literal string";
const size_t  len = strlen(pc +1);    //  space to allocate

//  performance test on string allocation and copy
for (size_t ix = 0; ix != 1000000; ++ix) {
    char *pc2 = new char[len + 1];  //  allocate the space
    strcpy(pc2, pc);                //  do the copy
    if (strcmp(pc2, pc))            //  use the new string
        ;    //  do nothing
    delete [] pc2;                  //  free the memory
}

//  string implementation
string str("a very long literal string");

//  performance test on string allocation and copy
for(int ix = 0; ix != 1000000; ++ix) {
    string str2 = str;  //  do the copy, automatically allocated
    if (str != str2)    //  use the new string
        ;   //  do nothing
}    //  str2 is automatically freed
```

Now bear in mind that **I'm aware of** that `strlen(pc +1)` on line 2, and that the first `for` uses `size_t` but doesn't subscript the array so it might as well have been `int`, but this is exactly how it is written down in the book.

When I test this code (with `strlen(pc) + 1`, which I presume was intended), my results are that the first block executes about **50% faster** than the second block, which leads to conclusion that **C-style strings are faster than library string class for this particular example**.

However, I bet I'm missing something (probably obvious), because of what is written in the book (page 139) relating to the code above:

> As it happens, on average, the string class implementation executes
>   considerably faster than the C-style string functions. The relative
>   average execution times on our more than five-year-old PC are as
>   follows:

```
 user    0.47  # string class 
 user    2.55  # C-style character string
```

So which one is it? Should I have used a longer string literal? Maybe it was because they used the GNU C Compiler and I used the Microsoft one? Is it because I have a faster computer?

Or is the book just wrong on this one?

#### Edit

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86

Comment: Have you tried different optimization levels with your c++ compiler?

Comment: I'm not even aware they exist, could you test the code above using those methods and see if the results match the authors?

Comment: And could you tell us about your c++ compiler? Is it vc++, if so which one? To my knowledge they should be just about equal.

Comment: Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86, is what it says, and I invoke it like so: `cl -EHsc a.cpp`

Comment: You didn't enable any optimization, so the benchmark isn't significant (STL classes without optimizations enabled are known to perform badly). Try to add at least `/O2`.

Comment: How would I enable such optimization?

Comment: Add `/O2` to the command line. For programs composed of several files you should really add also `/GL`.

Comment: Adding `O2` to the command line improves results significantly for library string, but they are still about 5% slower than C-style strings. Do you have any other optimization options?

Comment: I don't know, maybe the `std::string` implementation shipped with VC++ isn't that good, or `g++` optimizes worse the C string operations, because on my PC with g++ and `-O3` I get 0.632s (C++) vs 3.592s (C) (for 100000000 iterations).

Comment: I guess it depends the situation. Appending a string, copying the string, deleting 1 character, iterating through, memory footprint... they both must have their pros and cons; but really, they are just chars. Any string class is there to make your life easier when programming, only for that the gain is worth it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your conclusion that C style strings are faster with this example with your compiler & machine, is almost certainly because  – one must presume – you

- forgot to turn on optimization,
- forgot to make the string length "unknown" to the compiler (this is tricky) so as to prevent it from optmizing away `strlen` calls, and
- forgot and turn off safety range checking (if applicable) which would slow down `std::string`.

Here's the code I tested with:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

extern void doNothing( char const* );

class StopWatch
{
private:
    clock_t     start_;
    clock_t     end_;
    bool        isRunning_;
public:
    void start()
    {
        assert( !isRunning_ );
        start_ = clock();
        end_ = 0;
        isRunning_ = true;
    }

    void stop()
    {
        if( isRunning_ )
        {
            end_ = clock();
            isRunning_ = false;
        }
    }

    double seconds() const
    {
        return double( end_ - start_ )/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }

    StopWatch(): start_(), end_(), isRunning_() {}
};

inline void testCStr( int const argc, char const* const argv0 )
{
    //  C-style character string implementation
    //const char *pc = "a very long literal string";
    const char *pc = (argc == 10000? argv0 : "a very long literal string");
    //const size_t  len = strlen(pc +1);    //  space to allocate
    const size_t  len = strlen(pc)+1;    //  space to allocate

    //  performance test on string allocation and copy
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix != 1000000; ++ix) {
        char *pc2 = new char[len + 1];  //  allocate the space
        strcpy(pc2, pc);                //  do the copy
        if (strcmp(pc2, pc))            //  use the new string
            //;   //  do nothing
            doNothing( pc2 );
        delete [] pc2;                  //  free the memory
    }
}

inline void testCppStr( int const argc, char const* const argv0 )
{
    //  string implementation
    //string str("a very long literal string");
    string str( argc == 10000? argv0 : "a very long literal string" );

    //  performance test on string allocation and copy
    for(int ix = 0; ix != 1000000; ++ix) {
        string str2 = str;  //  do the copy, automatically allocated
        if (str != str2)    //  use the new string
            //;   //  do nothing
            doNothing( &str2[0] );
    }    //  str2 is automatically freed
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    StopWatch   timer;

    timer.start();  testCStr( argc, argv[0] );  timer.stop();
    cout << "C strings: " << timer.seconds() << " seconds." << endl;

    timer.start();  testCppStr( argc, argv[0] );  timer.stop();
    cout << "C++ strings: " << timer.seconds() << " seconds." << endl;
}
```

Typical result:

```
[d:\dev\test]
> g++ foo.cpp doNothing.cpp -O2

[d:\dev\test]
> a
C strings: 0.417 seconds.
C++ strings: 0.084 seconds.

[d:\dev\test]
> a
C strings: 0.398 seconds.
C++ strings: 0.082 seconds.

[d:\dev\test]
> a
C strings: 0.4 seconds.
C++ strings: 0.083 seconds.

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```

The said, C++ strings are not generally the fastest possible implementation of strings.

Generally, immutable strings (reference counted) beat C++ strings by a good margin, and, surprising to me when I learned that, a string implementation that simply copies the string data is faster still, when it uses an appropriate, fast custom allocator. However, don't ask me how to implement the latter. I only saw the code and test results in another forum, which someone graciously provided after I'd pointed out the general superiority of immutable strings in a discussion with STL and there was some disagreement. ;-)

Comment: Same result with your code: C-string 5% faster than C++ string, with argument `/O2` passed to compiler. What compiler and optimization did you use?

Comment: @NikoDrašković: can you please post the full actual compiler invocation you used, as well as the compiler version?

Comment: Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86, is what it says on invoke, and I used `-cl /O2 b.cpp`. This if from Visual Studio Command Prompt, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Ok, so I've gone so far as to install Linux, and when compiled with `g++ -O3 b.cpp`, the results are the same as yours. I guess that was the problem.

Comment: @NikoDrašković: the third point in the answer is to turn off range checking. apparently you're linking with the debug version of the runtime library. in visual studio that means you're building a "Debug" version; build a "Release" version instead

Comment: Hmm, I'm not using Visual Studio to build, I'm using command line. Could you specify which options to use to build the release version?

Comment: @NikoDrašković: first, clear the `CL` environment variable (command `set CL=`, with no extra spaces). then just don't specify anything more than the two source files and option `/O2`. the results you got earlier were very different from what a proper release build would yield.

Comment: With the `CL` variable cleared, `cl /O2 a.cpp` (on Windows) gives: c string: 2.7 sec, C++ string: 1.2 sec. Same code, same machine (now Ubuntu) with GCC `g++ -O3 a.cpp` gives: c string: 0.35 sec, c++ string: 0.07 sec. Second test is on the order of magnitude faster, which is odd.

Comment: You might (or might not) see a greater difference with the `doNothing` function in its own file.

Comment: When `doNothing` isn't called, c++ strings outperform c strings by a factor of 5. When `doNothing` is called (ifs set to equal), then c strings outperform c++ strings by about 50%... But even so, the microsoft compiler version is 10 times slower.

Comment: hm, you might want to discuss this further in [the C++ lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec). apparently you're doing something not quite correct. but the commentary here is not well suited to clear that up.

Answer (score 7):

First of all: **there is no definitive answer to this question.**

The reason is that the performance depends on the library implementation, the compiler and the options you use, the operating system you use and the CPU architecture you use.

The book is somewhat old(2005, hardware & software have evolved), and the code it has has been tested on old compilers, on old implementations and on old hardware. Whatever it says about the performance is based on the observations by it's authors which definitely would vary between different people trying out the code with different compiler, library and hardware combinations.

The best you can do, is to try yourself. Simple "benchmarks" like these won't tell much about performance between C-style strings vs. `std::string`s in *real world*, common situations unless they provide extensive coverage of as many possible ways to test and compare the performance as possible - something which would be quite a big project itself.

Note that compiler optimizations can deceive you with code like shown in the book. For example because of the empty `if`-blocks, the whole `if`-statement and the expression within it(in this case for example call to strcpy) can be removed(*). It can be **very** hard to do meaningful, real-world applicable benchmarks with code blocks as given in the book.

Also note that whatever the results of these micro-benchmarks turns out to be, only applies to the operations they benchmark - in other words - just because string allocation, copy and comparison seem to be *x* times faster with either `std::string` or C-style string, does not mean that the other is *x* times faster than the other in general!

*: Tested the C-style string code with GCC 4.7.1 with `-Ofast` and there is no reference to `strcmp` in the compiled executable, suggesting that the string comparison was eliminated as unnecessary in the code - which it indeed *is* - because the `if`-block is empty so there's no reason to even have the whole `if` there in the first place!

To add my own observations: I broke the two pieces of code to distinct functions and then made 100 repeated calls(with a `for`-loop) to one of them and then measured the running time with the `time` unix-utility. Compiled with GCC 4.7.1 and `-Ofast`.

100 calls to the C-Style string function took about 7.05 seconds(3 runs, variation between 7 and 7.1 seconds) while the 100 calls to the std::string version took **only** around 1.4 seconds on average over 3 runs! Indeed, this would suggest that std::string far outperforms C-style strings.

Comment: Nice idea to check if compiler removes the `if`s, however, even with those modification I get the same result, c string 5% faster than c++ string. You don't happen to have a Microsoft compiler to test this with? :)

Comment: Having tested this on a Linux distribution (freshly installed, mind you!), with a GCC (the newest one) `g++ -O3 a.cpp`, the results are similar to what the authors had said (and what all you have said), so I guess it was really a compiler thing.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a fair comparison, **std::string** may use techniques like *copy on write*. Given your timing results I would guess **str2** isn't creating a copy at all, rather a reference to **str**, which not only saves on the allocation and copy, but may make the comparison a *nop* as well. Also using **strcpy()** is suboptimal since it needs to check for a terminator. For a more honest comparison, I would suggest the following revisions:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
inline void testCStr(const int argc, const char* argv)
{
    const char* str = (argc == 10000) ? argv : "a very long literal string";
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
     {
        char* dup = (char*) malloc(len + 1);
        memcpy(dup, str, len + 1);
        dup[0] = str[0]; /* keep things even. */
        if (strcmp(str, dup))
            doNothing(dup);
        free(dup);
     }
}

inline void testCppStr(const int argc, const char* argv)
{
    string str = (argc == 10000) ? argv : "a very long literal string";

    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
     {
        string dup = str;
        dup[0] = str[0]; // force copy (defeats copy on write).
        if (str != dup)
           doNothing(dup.c_str());
     }
}
```

C++ interfaces are so streamlined and simple, it's easy to overlook how much is actually going on *under the hood*. The reality is, if both code sequences are written in an equivalent way with respect to the language, performance should be roughly equivalent as well.

A version of **testCStr()** that is *functionally equivalent* to the original **testCppStr()**, might be written as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* utility. */
static int strcmpx(const char* x, size_t xsize, const char* y, size_t ysize)
{
    int cmp = memcmp(x, y, xsize);
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;
    return -(xsize < ysize);
}

/* mystring. */
typedef struct mystring {
    long* refcnt;
    char* cstr;
    size_t size;
} mystring;

/* mystring private. */
static inline int mystring_unique(const mystring* x)
{   return *x->refcnt == 1;
}

static inline void mystring_add_ref(const mystring* x)
{   ++*x->refcnt;
}

static void mystring_del_ref(mystring* x)
{
    int unique = mystring_unique(x);
    --*x->refcnt;

    if (unique)
        free(x->refcnt);
}

static void mystring_make_unique(mystring* x, const char* str, size_t size)
{
    void* base = malloc(size + 1 + sizeof (long));
    x->refcnt = (long*) base;
    *x->refcnt = 1;

    x->cstr = (char*) base + sizeof (long);
    memcpy(x->cstr, str, size + 1);
    x->size = size;
}

/* mystring public. */
void mystring_construct(mystring* x, const char* str)
{   mystring_make_unique(x, str, strlen(str));
}

void mystring_construct_copy(mystring* x, const mystring* src)
{
    mystring_add_ref(src);
    *x = *src;
}

void mystring_destroy(mystring* x)
{   mystring_del_ref(x);
}

int mystring_cmp(const mystring* x, const mystring* y)
{   return strcmpx(x->cstr, x->size, y->cstr, y->size);
}

const char* mystring_cstr(const mystring* x)
{   return x->cstr;
}

const char* mystring_at_const(const mystring* x, long i)
{   return x->cstr + i;
}

char* mystring_at(mystring* x, long i)
{
    if (!mystring_unique(x))
     {
        mystring save = *x;
        mystring_make_unique(x, x->cstr, x->size);
        mystring_del_ref(&save);
     }
    return x->cstr + i;
}

/* test case. */
void testCStr(const int argc, const char* argv)
{
#define ITERATIONS 1000000
    const char* temp = (argc == 10000) ? argv : "a very long literal string";
    mystring str;
    mystring_construct(&str, temp);

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ )
     {
        mystring dup;
        mystring_construct_copy(&dup, &str);
#ifdef FORCE_COPY
        *mystring_at(&dup, 0) = *mystring_at_const(&str, 0);
#endif
        if (mystring_cmp(&str, &dup))
            doNothing(mystring_cstr(&dup));
        mystring_destroy(&dup);
     }
    mystring_destroy(&str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having agreed to what @zxcdw said, I'd like to add:

**There's no inherent reason that the library `std::string` should be (significantly) slower than the C-style string.**

`std::string` could actually be doing more work, because it could be checking boundaries on each element access (which you should be able to turn off with a compile-time option), etc. It could actually be doing less work, because it knows the length (hence the end) of the string and doesn't have to search for it when you append something. **So you never know (without measuring).**

On the other hand, knowing more means a bigger memory footprint (two pointers instead of one), and this could also affect the performance (due to more cache misses) when you deal with lots of different string objects in a short time. But I don't think this is what's happening in your case.

Comment: Yeah and I believe std::string does some memory allocation and retention? ...kind of like a vector of chars? Because then appending another string means re-allocating new memory, copying ,deleting, et cetera. I'm not 100% sure; again it's implementation specific I think.

Comment: Well, there *is* an inherent reason why C style string will be slower for unoptimized version of the OP's code, namely that it has to compute the string length. If the compiler is not prevented from optimizing that, however, a modern compiler will realize that the string length is known at compile time, and moreover, due to the simplicity of the C string operations it may realize that the final effect is zero so that it all can be just removed. This is quite different from more realistic code where the strings are unknown to the compiler, and where the action is actually doing something.

Comment: @AlexBelanger: > Because then appending another string means re-allocating new memory. Not always correct. Most strings will be optimised to allocate a power of 2 which would be amortised constant time.